# Communicate between components when routing in angular 7

Tags: angular-routing

here I'm routing one component to another using routerLink and also using [queryParams] to pass parameters.

RouterLink and everything works fine but when I pass parameters using [queryParams], all these parameters shows in the url which is not expected. Because I want to keep my url fresh and readable.

```
Example:
<html>
 <div routerLink="/list/article" [queryParams]="{tag: 'news', order: 'asscending', largeImage="true"}
</html>
```

I don't wanna show my queryParams on the url. Is there any trick or any other ways to avoid this issue.

Thanks in advance sir.

Comment: Please check this:
https://therichpost.com/how-to-share-data-between-two-components-in-angular-7

Comment: Sorry sir, this is not what I need...